# Using variable instead of a cat output

Tags: shell-script, shell, pipe, variable

In a shell script how can I get the same output from a variable for piping like a command does (for example: `cat data.dat | awk ...`)?

```
list=`cat data.dat`
```

then update list with running it through awk.

Comment: It's unclear what the purpose of your loop is.

Comment: The purpose of it is to filter continuosly by the parameters. I chose this way because i also have to filter only by the 4th field of the input.

Comment: You can simplify your awk to `awk -F ";" -v keyword="key" '$4~keyword'`, since "print" is the default action and specifying conditions as awk "patterns" is cleaner.

Comment: It's still unclear what you want to do. Where is the keyword read from? Is it coming from the same file that you run the `awk` program is running over? Can you describe with words tho overall problem that you are trying to solve by writing this script?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear I just wanted to give a little context. 

The problem was that I wanted to substitute the awk piped input from `cat data.dat` with a variable (the same `list` variable).

The accepted answer works with `list="$(echo "$list" | awk -F ";" -v keyword="$i" '{ if ($4~keyword) { print }}')"`

Comment: With bash, you can write `list=$(<data.dat)` -- `$(<...)` is a bash builtin

Comment: I meant, what is all this actually doing? What does `data.dat` contain and what do you actually want as output?  It may well be that it's easier to de some other way than to `echo` a string through `awk` in a loop. Running `awk` multiple times over small pieces of text from a file is almost never the right thing to do.

Comment: Is this a quoting problem? I don't fully understand the question, but it looks like you are not quoting properly. The `$(cat data.dat)` is being evaluated. As it is not in single quotes. Read the bash manual on quoting (`'` and `"`).

Comment: I wanted to pipe a variable (list) into awk, just like I could pipe a file (with cat) into it. I was looking for the correct syntax, and `echo "$list"` gives the same output as `cat data.dat` (if they have the same content). Sorry if it was unclear I'm a beginner with shell scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try as

```
export list
```

and in your list-assignment, use

```
echo $list | awk - - - --
```

Comment: Thank you, it almost did work, just needed extra quotes around $list so it had the line feeds too (like the cat data.dat had).

Comment: Using `export` is not needed here. The variable is not used by an external command.

Comment: @peter **a)** you should use `printf %s "$list"` instead of `echo` **b)** you should use `"$@"` instead of `$*` **c)** if you just want to filter all lines whose 4th field matches one of the keywords in argv, you can simply do it with `list=$(IFS='|'; awk -F';' -v kw="$*" '$4~kw' data.dat)`, no need for any loop.

Comment: Thanks @mosvy this is more elegant, but it's not filtering to include all the keywords, gives back rows which contains at least one.

Comment: @peter if you have a file where the lines are fields separated with `;`, and you want to find all lines in which the 4th field contains **all** the keywords from a list, no matter the order they're in (as it was in your original question that you trashed, why?), you can do it with this: `mgrep(){ r=; for a; do r="$r(?=.*\b$a\b)"; done; grep -P "([^;]*;){3}$r"; }` then `mgrep <file "$@"` or `mgrep <file kw1 kw2 ...`. Please make another question with your **actual** problem, since your approach was deficient and could probably be done much easier even without GNU extensions.